# NGNIX server blocks didn't work

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, virtualhost, centos7

I have 4 websites on VPS ip `104.207.148.242`. I have been install NGNIX 1.8.1 successful.

I do these steps:
Make web directories:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/codingvn.com/html
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/vyhn.net/html
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/muabannhadatpro.com/html
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/thenao.info/html
```

Set permissions:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/codingvn.com/html
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/vyhn.net/html
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/muabannhadatpro.com/html
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/thenao.info/html
```

Initialize index files:

```
nano /var/www/codingvn.com/html/index.html
nano /var/www/vyhn.net/html/index.html
nano /var/www/muabannhadatpro.com/html/index.html
nano /var/www/thenao.info/html/index.html
```

This is the content of file `/var/www/codingvn.com/html/index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Success! The codingvn.com server block is working!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the content of file `/var/www/vyhn.net.com/html/index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Success! The vyhn.net server block is working!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the content of file `/var/www/muabannhadatpro.com/html/index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Success! The muabannhadatpro.com server block is working!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the content of file `/var/www/thenao.info/html/index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Success! The thenao.info server block is working!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I copy default configuration files:

```
sudo cp /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/codingvn.com.conf
sudo cp /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/vyhn.net.conf
sudo cp /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/muabannhadatpro.com.conf
sudo cp /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/thenao.info.conf
```

I edit them:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/codingvn.com.conf
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/vyhn.net.conf
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/muabannhadatpro.com.conf
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/thenao.info.conf
```

This is file `codingvn.com.conf`:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name codingvn.com www.codingvn.com;

    location / {
        root  /var/www/codingvn.com/html/index.html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

x

This is file `vyhn.net.conf`:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name vyhn.net www.vyhn.net;

    location / {
        root  /var/www/vyhn.net/html/index.html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

x

This is file `muabannhadatpro.com.conf`:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name muabannhadatpro.com www.muabannhadatpro.com;

    location / {
        root  /var/www/muabannhadatpro.com/html/index.html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

x
This is file `thenao.info.conf`:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name thenao.info www.thenao.info;

    location / {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  /var/www/thenao.info/html/index.html;
    }

    error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

I have enough 4 configuration files at per directory:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/
/etc/nginx/sites-enable/
```

Then

```
service nginx restart
```

Then edit hosts /etc/hosts file:

```
104.207.148.242 codingvn.com
104.207.148.242 vyhn.net
104.207.148.242 thenao.info
104.207.148.242 muabannhadatpro.com
```

They not work, then:

```
127.0.0.1 codingvn.com
127.0.0.1 vyhn.net
127.0.0.1 thenao.info
127.0.0.1 muabannhadatpro.com
```

3 domains still not work. Only `codingvn.com` work.

I stuck at here. so tired, help me!

Comment: you shouldn't have `index.html` in the root path to start with. I don't see anywhere that you say you symlinked them to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

Comment: You are true. It is exactly my reason. It works (4 domains). Then I reinstall, althought have enought 4 files `index.html` at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`, they don't work again, I don't understand why.

Comment: The conf files need to be linked to sites-enabled not the html files